# Mobx, How is `@action` handled using the callback function

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I want to put the HTTP operation in the store instead of in the component, which will face a problem. I want to pop up toast after the HTTP error, which should be handled by the component.
I'd like to know what I should do. Thanks

This is my fake code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/j4m351ryw

```
  // store
  @action.bound
  async updateCount(_count, callback) {
    this.count = _count;
    try {
      // call http service
      const response = await MyService();
      if (response.error) {
        callback(response.error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      callback(error);
    }
  }

  // component
  click = () => {
    const store = this.props.store;
    // The way we do it now
    // Is there a better way to handle it
    store.updateCount(3, err => {
      if (err) {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this case in the next manner:

```
  // store
  @observable updateError = null;

  @action.bound
  async updateCount(_count, callback) {
    this.count = _count;
    try {
      // call http service
      const response = await MyService();
      if (response.error) {
        this.updateError = response.error;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.updateError = error;
    }
  }

  // component
  click = () => {
    this.props.store.updateCount(3);
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.store.updateError) {
      return <h1>Error happened during update. Details {this.props.store.updateError}<h1>
    }

    return <YourComponent/>
  }
```

The advantage of such solution is that you keep your business logic and your component logic separate and not mixing business logic with component event handlers code.

Comment: But I might want to perform in the`callback`. `this.props.history.goBack()`, inside the store to get `props`.